# MarkLogic custom collation

Tags: marklogic

Marklogic provides a collation builder (e.g. when creating a range index). This builder gives the ability to custom the collation. However, what I'm looking for is to have more control to custom the collation. For example,

- create a range index on a sub-string of the element content without
  the need to create a new element in the document
- ignore numbers
- custom sort (strings that start with number should be at the end of the search results.)

What I expect is to use a user defined function that control the collation behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There are no user defined collations in ML as of version 8 (nor I think in the upcoming version 9), but there are aggregate user defined functions that can operate over range indexes. MarkLogic provides a plug-in system that allows developers to build a map-reduce style function in C++ that, once compiled, can be called from XQuery. Depending on your exact use case, this may provide the type of high performance runtime sorting you want, without the need to create new elements.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/aggregateUDFs